# How do I block a button and raise a toast when the value of the product is lower, for a minimum price

Tags: java, android

I want to stipulate a minimum value of purchase, for example 50 reais, and that if the customer does not reach this value he is not allowed to continue the purchase, but I do not know how to do this in android studio.
Example:-

[image]

---

Sorry, I still do not know how to do this that you mentioned, I'm attaching the file to which the image belongs, if you can help me I'd be very grateful. Or if you could write an example for me, I would be very grateful. Thank you

```
public class My_Cart extends Fragment {

    public TextView cart_total_price;

    RecyclerView cart_items_recycler;
    LinearLayout cart_view, cart_view_empty;
    Button cart_checkout_btn, continue_shopping_btn;

    CartItemsAdapter cartItemsAdapter;
    User_Cart_DB user_cart_db = new User_Cart_DB();

    List<CartProduct> cartItemsList = new ArrayList<>();


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_cart, container, false);


        //Aviso de Pedido Minimo

        Alerter.create(getActivity())
                .setTitle(getString(R.string.cart_amount))
                .setText(getString(R.string.cart_amount_text))
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_cart_empty)
                .setIconColorFilter(1) // Optional - Removes white tint
                .setBackgroundColorRes(R.color.orderpending)
                .enableSwipeToDismiss()
                .enableProgress(true)
                .setDuration(15000)
                .show();


        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        // Enable Drawer Indicator with static variable actionBarDrawerToggle of MainActivity
        MainActivity.actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.actionCart));

        // Get the List of Cart Items from the Local Databases User_Cart_DB
        cartItemsList = user_cart_db.getCartItems();


        // Binding Layout Views
        cart_view = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cart_view);
        cart_total_price = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cart_total_price);
        cart_checkout_btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cart_checkout_btn);
        cart_items_recycler = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cart_items_recycler);
        cart_view_empty = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cart_view_empty);
        continue_shopping_btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.continue_shopping_btn);


        // Change the Visibility of cart_view and cart_view_empty LinearLayout based on CartItemsList's Size
        if (cartItemsList.size() != 0) {
            cart_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            cart_view_empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            cart_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cart_view_empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }



        // Initialize the AddressListAdapter for RecyclerView
        cartItemsAdapter = new CartItemsAdapter(getContext(), cartItemsList, My_Cart.this);

        // Set the Adapter and LayoutManager to the RecyclerView
        cart_items_recycler.setAdapter(cartItemsAdapter);
        cart_items_recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));


        // Show the Cart's Total Price with the help of static method of CartItemsAdapter
        cartItemsAdapter.setCartTotal();


        cartItemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



        // Handle Click event of continue_shopping_btn Button
        continue_shopping_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putBoolean("isSubFragment", false);

                // Navigate to Products Fragment
                Fragment fragment = new Products();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.main_fragment, fragment)
                        .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                        .addToBackStack(getString(R.string.actionCart)).commit();

            }
        });

        // Handle Click event of cart_checkout_btn Button
        cart_checkout_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                // Check if cartItemsList isn't empty
                if (cartItemsList.size() != 0) {

                    // Check if User is Logged-In
                    if (ConstantValues.IS_USER_LOGGED_IN) {

                        // Navigate to Shipping_Address Fragment
                        Fragment fragment = new Shipping_Address();
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment, fragment)
                                .addToBackStack(getString(R.string.actionCart)).commit();

                    } else {
                        // Navigate to Login Activity
                        Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), Login.class);
                        getContext().startActivity(i);
                        ((MainActivity) getContext()).finish();
                        ((MainActivity) getContext()).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_out_left);
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }


    public void updateCartView(int cartListSize) {

        // Check if Cart has some Items
        if (cartListSize != 0) {
            cart_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            cart_view_empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            cart_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cart_view_empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }


    public static void AddCartItem(CartProduct cartProduct) {
        User_Cart_DB user_cart_db = new User_Cart_DB();
        user_cart_db.addCartItem
                (
                        cartProduct
                );
    }


    public static CartProduct GetCartProduct(int product_id) {
        User_Cart_DB user_cart_db = new User_Cart_DB();

        CartProduct cartProduct = user_cart_db.getCartProduct
                (
                        product_id
                );

        return cartProduct;
    }

    public static void UpdateCartItem(CartProduct cartProduct) {
        User_Cart_DB user_cart_db = new User_Cart_DB();
        user_cart_db.updateCartItem
                (
                        cartProduct
                );
    }

    public static void DeleteCartItem(int cart_item_id) {
        User_Cart_DB user_cart_db = new User_Cart_DB();
        user_cart_db.deleteCartItem
                (
                        cart_item_id
                );
    }

    public static void ClearCart() {
        User_Cart_DB user_cart_db = new User_Cart_DB();
        user_cart_db.clearCart();
    }

    public static int getCartSize() {
        int cartSize = 0;

        User_Cart_DB user_cart_db = new User_Cart_DB();
        List<CartProduct> cartItems = user_cart_db.getCartItems();

        for (int i=0;  i<cartItems.size();  i++) {
            cartSize += cartItems.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getCustomersBasketQuantity();
        }

        return cartSize;
    }




    public static boolean checkCartHasProduct(int cart_item_id) {
        User_Cart_DB user_cart_db = new User_Cart_DB();
        return user_cart_db.getCartItemsIDs().contains(cart_item_id);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Hide Cart Icon in the Toolbar
        MenuItem cartItem = menu.findItem(R.id.toolbar_ic_cart);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.toolbar_ic_search);
        cartItem.setVisible(false);
        searchItem.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

[Link: My Cart](http://%20http://www.mediafire.com/file/epa9uyv8wi69yo2/My_Cart.java)

Answer (score 0):

Update `button.setEnabled()` with every change in value of product. Enable it only when product value qualifies. When clicked on disabled button, you could show some `Toast` message

Answer (score 0):

You must be using an ArrayList to store product details available in the cart. When ever a product is added to the cart, the total value is calculated,keep that value in a static variable.When you navigate to the cart activity/fragment, check for the variable value using your minimum value condition, if it satisfies your condition, set `button.setEnabled(true)` & `button.setClickable(true)` else set both to false. Alternatively you can change the background color of the button too and make it disabled & unclickable.